# mouseenter, mouseleave, hover jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, mouseover

I'm having a problems with these event.  I'm not sure what is the best to use.  I'm trying to do some opacity animation depending on where the mouse is.

I have these structure

```
    <div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
<a href="#">         
<img class="thumb" src="image/image1.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">    
<img class="thumb" src="image/image2.png" />
</a>
<a href="">    
<img class="thumb" src="image/image3.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">    
<img class="thumb" src="image/image4.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">    
<img class="thumb" src="image/image5.png" />
</a>    
</div>
```

Basically, what i want to do is whenever the mouse enters the image, the rest of the images (other than the where the mouse is) will do animate opacity change ie: `$(img).stop().not(this).animate({"opacity":"0.4"})` 
and where the one mouse is will animate to opacity:1.

Please help what is the best approach to this.  I tried hover but i was unsuccessful.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [`.delegate()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for binding an event handler to the wrapping `div.thumbnail-wrapper`. Catching all `mouseenter` events from the `<img>` nodes there. Use [`.fadeTo()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) and [`.siblings()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to accomplish the task.

Example:

```
$('div.thumbnail-wrapper').delegate('a', 'mouseenter', function(e) {
    $(this).stop(1,0).fadeTo('fast', 1).siblings().stop(1,0).fadeTo('fast', 0.2);
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/qR2NU/2/
<sup>(I'm using `div` nodes in the example, you would need to replace `div` with `img` in the `.delegate()` arguments)</sup>

Comment: @jAndy Sorry, i edited the HTML, how can i revise it coz the img is wrapped with <a> see updated html.. thanks

Comment: hi jAndy.. just a question, inside the delegate fn, 'e.target' is equal to the 'this'?

Comment: @steweb: not necessarilly! Imagine the `<img>` tags would be wrapped by a `<span>`, then the `e.target` would represent the `span` and `this` the `<img>`. So in general it would be better to use `$(this)`.

Comment: @Marvzz: just replace the `img` with `a` as target nodes then. I updated the answer.

Comment: @jAndy, this is working now on the demo, but when i tried it locally, i get .delegate is not a function?

Comment: @Marvzz: `.delegate()` requires jQuery 1.4.2+

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.thumbnail-wrapper img') //all images under the wrapper
  .bind('mouseenter',function (){//when mouseenter,blur me,focus my siblings
     $(this).animate({"opacity":"0.4"}).siblings().animate({"opacity":"1"});
}).bind('mouseleave',function (){// when mouse out, default state or (make me sober as i call it )
     $(this).animate({"opacity":"1"})
});
```

Comment: hi, ive edited my html, I cannot seem to make it work with hover? can you elaborat more the implementation?

Comment: when mouse enter i want to blur the rest, not the one selected.

Comment: change opacity `0.4` to `1` and `1` to `0.4` should be ok

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumbnail-wrapper img').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().animate({'opacity': 0.4});
}, function(){
    $(this).siblings().animate({'opacity': 1});
});
```